# How to convert this SQL so that it uses less subqueries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT s.id, s.show_start, s.show_end, s.bekeken, s.website, s.afbeelding,
         (SELECT titel FROM serie_details WHERE taalcode = 'oo' AND serie_id = s.id) AS titel,
         (SELECT beschrijving FROM serie_details WHERE taalcode = 'oo' AND serie_id = s.id) AS beschrijving,
         ARRAY_AGG(d.titel) AS alt_titels,
         (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(num[1]) FROM afleveringen WHERE serie_id = s.id) AS afleveringen,
         (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM afleveringen WHERE serie_id = s.id) AS totaal
FROM series AS s
LEFT JOIN serie_details AS d ON d.serie_id = s.id
WHERE s.id = 6
GROUP BY s.id, s.show_start, s.show_end, s.bekeken, s.website, s.afbeelding
```

`series` is the table with the series, `serie_details` contains alternative names for series and `afleveringen` contains episode numbers and titles for those episodes.

I've tried using multiple JOINs but then I get duplicated results, because there are multiple rows in the `serie_details` table. The query was:

```
SELECT s.id, s.show_start, s.show_end, s.bekeken, s.website, s.afbeelding, COUNT(a.id) AS totaal,
         (select titel from serie_details where taalcode = 'oo' and serie_id = s.id) AS titel,
         (select beschrijving from serie_details where taalcode = 'oo' and serie_id = s.id) AS beschrijving,
         ARRAY_AGG(a.num[1]) AS afleveringen,
         ARRAY_AGG(d.titel) AS alt_titels
FROM series AS s
LEFT JOIN afleveringen AS a ON a.serie_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN serie_details AS d ON d.serie_id = s.id
WHERE s.id = 6
GROUP BY s.id, s.show_start, s.show_end, s.bekeken, s.website, s.afbeelding
```

Comment: Is there any reason you'd like less sub-queries? You're basically just doing a JOIN on a smaller data set that way.

Comment: Purely for performance reasons.

Comment: Do you know you'll get an improvement in performance?

Comment: I'm not sure but that's what I'd like to test out.

Comment: Have you already created some indexes? They might speed up your query

Comment: I'm still in the development process so adding indexes will be for later. Now I try to create the queries in an optimal way as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT s.id, s.show_start, s.show_end, s.bekeken, s.website, s.afbeelding,
          x.titel,
          x.beschrijving,
          ARRAY_AGG(d.titel) AS alt_titels,
          y.afleveringen,
          y.totaal
     FROM SERIES s
LEFT JOIN serie_details AS d ON d.serie_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sd.serie_id,
                  sd.titel,
                  sd.beschrijving
             FROM SERIE_DETAILS sd
            WHERE sd.taalcode = 'oo') x ON x.serie_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.serie_id,
                  ARRAY_AGG(num[1]) AS afleveringen,
                  COUNT(id) AS totaal
             FROM afleveringen a
         GROUP BY a.serie_id) y ON y.serie_id = s.id
    WHERE s.id = 6
 GROUP BY s.id, s.show_start, s.show_end, s.bekeken, s.website, s.afbeelding, x.titel, x.beschrijving, y.afleveringen, y.totaal
```

You realize you were missing GROUP BY clauses?

Comment: I tried adding `GROUP BY` columns but then the query was returning multiple rows.

Comment: @EarthMind: Well, your query is returning the `titel` col as a single column AND as an aggregate array - I gather you really only want the aggregate array.  But then you have to deal with the `beschrijving` column...

Comment: The reason why there's also a single column `titel` is because I want to use the official title as default (where taalcode = 'oo') and select the rest of the titles as an aggregate array (where taalcode = 'en', 'fr', etc.) without any complex queries.

Comment: @EarthMind: I understand; I don't have data & a limited concept of your data model so I dunno what is valid & isn't.  So which column(s) are giving you duplicates?

Comment: The serie with `id = 6` has two records in the `serie_details` table and 14 records in the `afleveringen` table and my query with multiple left joins returned 28 for `count(afleveringen.id)` and duplicates of the `serie_details.titel` column.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to leave it using the subqueries.  Not sure about postgressql, but ms sql optimizes those just fine.

Comment: No it doesn't, correlated subqueries cause huge performance problems becasue they force roww-by row processing. Joins are almost always significantly faster.

Comment: @HLGEM: subqueries vs a join with a large group by? your kidding right?